# how to print saved spreadsheet in java swing?

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable, apache-poi

I have a table in my project and I stored the table contents in a spreadsheet .XLs format using hssf work book Apache POI.
when I press the print button I want this saved spreadsheet to print , the print dialog popup, how to do this I have tried Java `printerjob` but `setPrintable` only accept the printable object but I have a file to print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build your Excel file then,
Use Desktop on java.awt

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
desktop.print(new File("file.xlsx"));
} catch (Exception e) {           
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: its working but the dialog box just come and go...it is not staying

Comment: can you please give me fiddle example

Comment: hey @ashokramcse I have to print the .`xls` file and your solution worked for me however problem is it only prints the active sheet and my file has many sheets. How do I print them all at once through code?